# Using airprint for SMB printer

Tags: network, printing, smb

I am trying to print using a HP LaserJet Enterprise M609 connected with `spoolss` (i.e. `smb`).  I can connect and authenticate with other printers that way, and they all print using the 'generic postscript driver', but this printer does not work with this driver, for reasons unknown.  Apple lists it as one of the printers that would be able to use AirPrint, but this is not an option I can select.  Any idea how to tell the printer to use AirPrint?

The steps I need to follow are the same as [these](https://it.faa.illinois.edu/services/printing/57-printing-services/220-add-printer-mac-smb), and work for other printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be nothing to do with Airprint, but simply getting IT to changing the printer driver to Universal Printing PCL 6 (this was found by trial and error, nobody had a clue).  Live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student at University of Illinois Urbana-Champaign, you'll have to log in using your credentials so they can log your prints/charge you for your prints, which is currently incompatible with AirPrint. AirPrint can be disabled by your system administrator on a printer-by-printer basis.

[You may have better luck directly contacting your school's help desk.](https://helpdesk.faa.illinois.edu/portal)

Comment: nope I am not -- I am just using that web page to show the details of what I am doing